# Laurent Series computation

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, laurent-series

Need to compute the Laurent Series:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2} \quad on \quad 0<|z-i|<2$$

---

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i(z-i)} + \frac{i}{2(z+i)}$$

$$\frac{1}{2i(z-i)} = \frac{1}{2zi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{i}{z}\right)^k$$

$$\frac{i}{2(z+i)} = \frac{i}{2z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-i}{z}\right)^k$$

$$f(z)=\frac{i}{2z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^k-(i)^k}{z^k}$$

Is this correct? I cannot figure out a way to verify the answer.

Comment: For a Laurent series on an annulus with centre $a$, we have an expansion of the form $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k (z-a)^k$. Your expansion isn't of this form so at least isn't the correct expansion on the given annulus.

Comment: Similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549809/laurent-series-of-frac11z2-on-a-given-set.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}$$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)}\cdot \frac{1}{(z+i)}$$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)}\cdot \frac{1}{2i-(i-z)}$$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)}\cdot \frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{(i-z)}{2i}} $$

Clearly $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-\frac{(i-z)}{2i}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(i-z)^n}{(2i)^n}$ whenever $\left|\frac{(i-z)}{2i} \right|<1 \Rightarrow 0<|z-i|<2$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)}\cdot \frac{1}{2i}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(i-z)^n}{(2i)^n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z-i)^{n-1}}{(2i)^{n+1}}$$

$$f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z-i)^{n-1}}{(2i)^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in the comments, for the given disk we are looking for a series of the form $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k (z-i)^k$$
You correctly calculated that $f(z) = \frac{1}{2i(z-i)} + \frac{i}{2(z+i)}$. Now you should note that the first term is $\frac{1}{2i}(z-i)^{-1}$ which is of the desired form so now we only need a series for the second term.

For convenience of notation let $w = z - i$. Then 
$$\frac{i}{2(z+i)} = \frac{i}{2}\frac{1}{w + 2i} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\frac{w}{2i} + 1}$$
Now note that $|\frac{w}{2i}|<1$ so this is the sum of the geometric series $$\frac{1}{\frac{w}{2i} + 1} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg (\frac{-w}{2i} \bigg)^k $$
This can all be put back together to get the correct Laurent series on the desired annulus.
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i}(z-i)^{-1} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg (\frac{-1}{2i} \bigg)^k(z-i)^k = \sum_{k=-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4} \bigg (\frac{-1}{2i} \bigg)^k(z-i)^k $$